# How to find and modify my.cnf on Mac Yosemite

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite, my.cnf

To locate my.cnf on Mac Yosemite I use Terminal and submit:
locate my.cnf

After that the location is shown (usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.8-x86_64/my.cnf)
but where is that exactly and how to open it through OSX? That's not a regular directory, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can Search my.cnf file executing:

```
$ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf
```

Is more problably find in this paths:

```
/Users/USER/mysql-VERSION-osxVERSION/my.cnf 
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score -1):

There's many ways that you could open this file for editing. Here are two simple options. In your Terminal, type:

```
nano /usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.8-x86_64/my.cnf
```

That will open the file in the nano text editor, right in your Terminal. You can make your edits and then use Ctrl-W to save the file and Ctrl-X to exit.

If you'd rather use a simple program like TextEdit, you can open the file with this command in your Terminal.

```
open -a TextEdit /usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.8-x86_64/my.cnf
```

That will open the file in TextEdit, where you can save it with Cmd-S, or via the menus.